# terminal warn on close when opened within a script

Tags: shell, shell-script

First, the question:
How can I warn the user that a script is running when the user clicks the close button and the terminal itself (and the process running in it) was started from the command line.

I have a script that performs actions that the user will want to reverse before the script terminates. There is a read statement that pauses the process until the user hits [enter]. But, a hapless user will occasionally click the close button [x] in the top right-hand corner. I have not found a trap that catches the close button, but a warning will do. The gnome-terminal provides the needed warning.

**But**, when the gnome-terminal is launched from a script (say a Thunar custom action) the feature does not work. To clarify, consider the script:

```
gnome-terminal --command="sh readx.sh"
```

Where readx.sh contains a single line: read x

On clicking the top right [x] button, a terminal launched this way closes without warning while the script is still active.

Any method for trapping or warning will work for me.

Comment: Try running `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c readx.sh;bash"`

Comment: That's close. The command will open the gnome terminal in warning mode. As written, the gnome terminal opens and then stumbles on the command readx.sh: bash: readx.sh: command not found.

Comment: May be add `./` before filename: `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c ./readx.sh;bash"` (if you're running it from current directory)

Comment: Yup. Been there, done that, even dropped in the entire filespec. Also tried as both an sh script and a bash script.

Comment: How about `gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./readx.sh;bash"

Comment: We're getting close. That last command will throw the warning, but only after the script is completed. That is, the gnome-terminal is closed without warning if the close button is clicked and readx.sh is still waiting for a response.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Including a zenity prompt works well for me. When the script is executed with nohup and a zenity prompt is included, the thread will block as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually detach you process of running `readx.sh` from terminal window, so even if you close the gnome-terminal window, it will continue to run in background and complete what it should do. In order to do this, you should use `nohup` command - it disconnects the process from the terminal, redirects its output to nohup.out and shields it from `SIGHUP`.

I tested it with the following command: `gnome-terminal -e "nohup bash ./123.sh"`
Script `123.sh` contains only `sleep 7 && ls -a > 1.txt`. So, when I run the previous command and close the window of gnome-terminal, file 1.txt is created nevertheless.

Comment: This answer applies to a script that can complete its task autonomously. The readx script requires user input from an interactive terminal. Like the readx script, the actual thunar custom action requires the following interaction:"please press enter to gracefully close your encrypted volume when you are through working with it." But your answer does provide an idea that may work: detach a script that blocks at a zenity dialogue. I'll give this a try... a zenity dialogue is probably less likely to be occidentally closed in an un-trappable way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this command to solve the issue.

```
Exec=mate-terminal -e "bash -i  -c 'ssh my.server';bash"
```

This command is just tested on `mate-terminal`, not `gnome-terminal`.

My `mate-terminal` version is 1.16.3 on CentOS7.